# ShareThis with dynamic share content using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharethis

I'm trying to alter the content shared by ShareThis buttons using JQuery:

```
      var services = [                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          "facebook",                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          "twitter",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          "linkedin",                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          "email",                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          "print"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      ];                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

      for (var i = 0, len = services.length; i < len; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                        
          stWidget.addEntry({                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              service: services[i],                                                                                                                                                                                                 
              element: document.getElementById("st_data_" + services[i]),                                                                                                                                                           
              url: window.location.href,                                                                                                                                                                                            
              title: $("#lblPropertyTitle").html(),                                                                                                                                                                                 
              type: "large",                                                                                                                                                                                                        
              text: services[i],                                                                                                                                                                                                    
              image: $(".carousel .carousel-inner .item[data-slide-number='0'] img").attr("src"),                                                                                                                                   
              summary: $("#lblPropertyDescription").html()                                                                                                                                                                          
          });                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      }
```

It just shares the base url with the default title and image.
How can I alter the title, description and image that it is shared?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and twitter use OG tags to determine the preview image for the url. You will need to define those on your page. Defining the image property for the stWidget entry is likely only good for email or print options.

To define open graph info for the page, add a meta tag like this...

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

You can validate your OG tags with some web tools.

- https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Documentation:

- [Twitter Card Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image)
- [Facebook OG Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

Comment: No, it has to be rendered server-side, or defined statically. Scripts don't run in the OG scraper. They just grab the html as text.